# Upload and read a txt file in zend without saving it

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I was wondering if its way in zend 1.12 that I can use to upload a txt file, read and make some parsing without have to save this file somewher.

I already have the upload form for that:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
        Chose your file: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

And also I've in the action:

```
function managementaccountingAction() {
        Zend_loader::loadClass('Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http');
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
            //$adapter->setDestination('C:\temp');
            //$files = $adapter->getFileInfo();  
            if (!$adapter->receive()) {
                $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
                echo implode("\n", $messages);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to save the file somewhere to do operations on it but you can delete it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to save the file somewhere to do operations on it but you can delete it afterwards.  In order to delete it, you can use the [PHP unlink function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

Comment: This is not entirely true. When a file is uploaded in PHP it is first saved to the OS's temporary files folder (`/tmp` fo Linux/Unix). Then you can just read it (load it in a fandler/stream) from there and disregard it since it will anyway be deleted on the next system restart. It is good however to `unlink()` it anyway.